# npm install single package from git repo not working

Tags: node.js, git, npm

So I have a dependancy like this in my package.json

```
"my-package": "git+https://urlToMyPackage/my-package.git#my-branch"
```

then if you do a "npm install my-package" this happens.

```
npm ERR! Linux 5.0.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "my-package"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not found : my-package
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'my-package' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/user/workdir/npm-debug.log
```

if I do a "npm install" it will install from my git repo along with all the other packages.  It seems then when you install a single package it doesn't check your package.json first to see if it's not installed from the npm registry.

Installing a single package from a git host used to work.  Is there a different npm command to do this now?

Answer (score 1):

For public Repository

```
"dependencies" : {
  "example" : "git://github.com/user/example.git#commit-ish"
}
```

And if your repository is private then first get oauth token from Github 
`Settings -> Applications -> Personal Access Token -> Generate new token`

```
"dependencies": {
"example": "git+https://<token-from-github>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<example>.git"
}
```

Comment: This is not hosted on GitHub.  Why is it searching the npm registry instead of going to my URL.